# Inheriting Instance Methods with Static References in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, inheritance, static

The following examples use [access modifiers from TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#member-visibility), but I think the question should also be relevant for JavaScript developers. Let's say I have some parent class, where I define some necessary members and an implementation of a shared method:

```js
// ParentClass.ts
export default class ParentClass {
  private static voo;
  private bar;

  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  private commonMethod(baz) {
    doSomething(ParentClass.voo);
    doSomethingElse(this.bar, baz);
  }
}
```

And then I have some child class, that inherits this behavior:

```js
// ChildClass.ts
export default class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    voo = "Jake";

    constructor(bar) {
        super(bar)
    }

    public uniqueMethod(ter) {
        doAnotherThing(this.bar);
        this.commonMethod(ter);
    }
}
```

Of course, when I call `commonMethod()` inside of `ChildClass.uniqueMethod()`, it will reference the value of `ParentClass.voo`, which is undefined. What I would like to happen is that each inheriting child class uses the *exact same* implementation of that method, but it references the static member of the child class itself. So when I call `ChildClass.uniqueMethod()`, `commonMethod()` will use the value from `ChildClass.voo()` rather than the parent equivalent.

One sidesteps this issue entirely by just making `voo` an instance member, rather than a static member, but let's say that you have some scenario where a static `voo` is more useful in other ways.

Is such a solution readily available? I've posted the solution that I'm currently using as a reply to this question, but I can't help but think there's a more direct solution out there.

Comment: Just a guess, have you tried `this.constructor.voo` instead of ParentClass.voo?

Comment: @BenTaber I haven't yet! I would think that the constructor wouldn't have any particular effect, since `voo` is a static member, and it isn't set by the constructor, but rather in the class definition. Does `this.constructor` really point to the class itself, as opposed to an instance of the class?

Comment: @BenTaber When I tried `this.constructor.voo`, I got: `Property 'voo' does not exist on type 'Function'.` It was worth a look though!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I currently have, where I'm attaching an instance accessor, and adjusting the `commonMethod()` to use that accessor:

```js
// ParentClass.ts
export default class ParentClass {
  private static _voo;
  private bar;

  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  public get voo() {
    return ParentClass._voo;
  }

  private commonMethod(baz) {
    doSomething(this.voo);
    doSomethingElse(this.bar, baz);
  }
}
```

And then inheriting classes override that accessor:

```js
// ChildClass.ts
export default class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    _voo = "Jake";

    constructor(bar) {
        super(bar)
    }

    public override get voo(){
        return ChildClass._voo
    }

    public uniqueMethod(ter) {
        doAnotherThing(this.bar);
        this.commonMethod(ter);
    }
}
```

This route doesn't seem very elegant to me, so I'd be very interested to hear feedback or suggestions about better ways to do this.